# what is the best way to broadcast emails using mail server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, email, email-server

the title says. but I mean send emails to many users without using cc and bcc

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "broadcast emails"

Comment: Do you want to use a tool, a script, a program?

Comment: the speed is important. scripts are fast and secure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(This question is very unclear: which OS? Which mailserver? So the answer below is probably too generic)

Use alias addresses. The implementation is different on most mailserver daemons though.

So behind alias address "all@example.org" there are "jerry@example.org, katie@example.org, albrecht@example.org" etc.

In Linux, most mail server implementations respect the file `/etc/aliases` where you can store your alias addresses.

Comment: in Windows Server 2008

Comment: Okay, after googling I found that if you're using Exchange you need to configure a "distribution group". All mails sent to this group will go to the users/e-mail addresses in it.